# php urlencode htmlentities issue

Tags: php, urlencode, html-entities

I'm getting an error:

`Warning: include(friday_set.php?x=First+Set&amp;y=2): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...`

When I go to my url -> "friday_set.php?x=First+Set&y=2" everything comes out how it should

I understand the main reason is that I'm not properly encoding the url and the url can't quantify the `&amp;` in the string

My code is this (which is similar to what is described in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) ):

```
<?php
 $sel_name = 'First Set';
 $admin_id = '2';

   $query_string = 'x=' . urlencode($sel_name) . "&y=" . urlencode($admin_id);
   include ("friday_set.php?" . htmlentities($query_string));
?>
```

I can't seem to spot the problem...anyone have a solution??

Comment: @Dagon - Thanks, but I don't see any information in that post that relates to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of parsing the vars in the file url i suggest this:

```
<?php
 $sel_name = 'First Set';
 $admin_id = '2';

   include ("friday_set.php");
?>
```

inside `friday_set.php` check for either `$_GET[x]` for direct url or `$sel_name` for include.

```
if(isset($_GET['x'])){
$sel_name=$_GET['x'];
}//else $sel_name  is just $sel_name unless you want to check its populated also
```

Comment: Lol...This is what I get when I try to over-complicate things. Thanks! Works great! I'll accept when it lets me